# I can't override CSS

Tags: customization, css

I recently bought a theme at ThemeForest.net called Greedt. The problem is that I cant edit theme's css in any way. I can't even edit parent theme code, same as in child theme that I created. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Here's my site: https://geekz.pl/

EDIT: Seems like I can’t edit CSS in editor under “appearance” but seems to work under “customize”. Any ideas how can I create working child theme?

Thanks

Comment: Usually it means that there is a stylesheet from the theme that loads after all the others. You should get help the people that created the theme, I'm sure they had that question many times. Many premium themes from theme forest also come with a child theme.

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't come with child theme and seems like the author dont understand my question. Do you have any advice how can I fix it?

Comment: I am also not sure I understand your question. I see the child theme css file as well as the one from the parent theme. You should be able to override the CSS rules within your child theme style.css file. If that doesn't work, double check the CSS selector and make sure the specificity is ok. If it still doesn`t work, let me know exactly which element you want to target and I can take a look.